# Can't select Operating System on dual-boot of Windows10 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows10. Everything went fine, At the Computer starts it lets me select Ubuntu or Windows10 to boot in BUT When i choose Windows10 once the Operating systems selecting menu is gone, Windows10 is boots automatically by default. and i don't see Ubuntu anymore Even if it's still there on my HDD partition.

Comment: I think i selected it from UEFI boot menu

Comment: Is this an HP. It and some others like to reset UEFI boot order. Some with HP have said updating UEFI from vendor and only changing boot order from within UEFI works. Most vendors should let you reset boot order with efibootmgr (which grub uses when it is installed in UEFI mode).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the fix for this is most likely (60% +/-) in UEFI (formerly called BIOS). Look for the key to press to get into setup on boot (often Delete or Enter). Suggest trying the following:

- Try setting boot mode to Legacy or Legacy first... This may be
  enough.
- Look at your boot drive options. You may see two rows for the
  same drive... One UEFI and the other not. Switch the order and see if it helps.

If neither worked, set them back the way they were just to keep it simple.

If it isn't one of those, it gets more complicated. Drive interface (AHCI or not) can matter. But it's not safe or always easily reversible to mess with that. And, it might be none of the above. You might have a corrupt boot loader for example.

Unfortunately there are a lot of potential issues with this same symptom. Good luck.